# How to setup CI on Magento 2 extension using Bitbucket Pipeline?

Tags: magento2, testing, automation, continuous-integration, bitbucket

How can I prepare a CI script to check the syntax and code quality of my extension code?

It's not necessary to run Unit Test or Integration Test, I'm using Bitbucket and I would like to use **Bitbucket Pipelines**.

Comment: If you also want to run tests on Bitbucket Pipelines, this might be helpful: https://www.integer-net.com/magento-api-tests-and-continuous-integration/

Comment: Maybe https://www.coderblog.de/running-magento-2-tests-via-bitbucket-pipelines/ helps :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the **AUTH** variable into the Pipelines Variable settings.

[image: Magento 2 Bitbucket Pipelines]

Using Bitbucket, you can use this file below called **bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```xml
    image: rafaelcgstz/magento2
    pipelines:
      branches:
        master:
          - step:
              name: Composer install
              caches:
                - composer
              artifacts:
                - vendor/**
              script:
                - echo "$AUTH" > auth.json
                - composer install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
          - parallel:
            - step:
                name: PHP CodeSniffer
                caches:
                  - composer
                artifacts:
                  - vendor/**
                script:
                  - php vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR2 Api/ Helper/ Model/ Plugin/ Setup/
            - step:
                name: PHP Mess Detector
                caches:
                  - composer
                artifacts:
                  - vendor/**
                script:
                  - php vendor/bin/phpmd Api/,Helper/,Model/,Plugin/,Setup/ text cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode
            - step:
                name: PHP Copy/Paste Detector
                caches:
                  - composer
                artifacts:
                  - vendor/**
                script:
                  - php vendor/bin/phpcpd Api/ Helper/ Model/ Plugin/ Setup/
```

Your **composer.json** needs to be like this below:

```
{
    "name": "mycompany/modulename",
    "description": "",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "authors":[
        {
            "name":"Rafael Correa Gomes",
            "email":"rgomes@magento.com"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-backend": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-catalog": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-eav": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-layered-navigation": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.5",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^2.0",
        "satooshi/php-coveralls": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "MyCompany\\ModuleName\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [Get started with Bitbucket Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines-792298921.html)

Comment: Exactly what I was lookinf for. Thanks! Maybe you can add an example how to setup unit/integration test?

Comment: If its your dockjer image, can you please add `phpstan` (v0.8.5)?

Comment: @sv3n did you figure out how to run the unit/integration test?

Comment: @rafael 

1. Why do you need the first step? it doesn't seem to be doing anything, unless I'm missing something obvious?
2. You are only passing in your magento username and password on the first step, our pipeline fails unless we pass in the credentials in every step

Comment: @Haim No need to pass the credentials on every step since required credentials are echoed to the auth.json.

Comment: @Haim The first step check if the composer packages exist and it will cache the packages, as Adnan said the other steps won't require your keys because all the packages are there as artifacts.